# Creating certificate using openssl in ubuntu os

Tags: openssl

i have to generate a digital certificate for any server lets say pkilabsever.com using the CA
I have a directory build with the following subdirectories

```
home/
demoCA/
certs
crl
index.txt
newcerts
openssl.cnf
serial
```

the problem is when i generate certificate using the following command ...

```
ghazal@ghazal-VirtualBox:/demoCA$ openssl ca -in server.csr -out server.crt -cert ca.crt -keyfile ca.key -config openssl.cnf
Using configuration from openssl.cnf
Enter pass phrase for ca.key:
I am unable to access the ./demoCA/newcerts directory
./demoCA/newcerts: No such file or directory
ghazal@ghazal-VirtualBox:/demoCA$
```

it is unable to find the subdirectories....
help plzz..

Comment: i know somebody else has asked that question but no appropriate solution there.... i have faced the same problem search many forums but know one give the right suggestions

Comment: :-/..............

Comment: nobody answer my question ....but i found the solution:-P